# SQL query for 3 tables by tour

Tags: sql

tourid

            tourname

        
        

            


                        1



                        PARIS


            

            


                        2



                        LANDON


            

            


                        3



                        MADRID


            

        
        


        

            tour_detail_ID

            tourid

            custid

        
        

            


                        1



                        1



                        3


            

            


                        2



                        2



                        3


            

            


                        3



                        3



                        3


            

            


                        4



                        1



                        4


            

            


                        5



                        2



                        4


            

            


                        6



                        3



                        4


            

            


                        7



                        1



                        5


            

            


                        8



                        2



                        5


            

        
        


        

            custid

            custname

            custPhoneNo

        
        

            


                        3



                        PETER



                        22332422


            

            


                        4



                        MARY



                        22332422


            

            


                        5



                        PAUL



                        22332422

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt3R9.png)

How can I get all customers booked all tours?

Comment: This is a very basic SQL question that definitely could have been answered by a quick google search.

Comment: Can you clean up your data display to be a bit clearer about what you're base data is?>

Comment: @lax1089 The question wasn't phrased well, and the jumbled data display didn't help, but I think what thanh is asking is a little more than just a simple, basic query. If I understand the question, he's looking for a list of the customers who have booked every tour, not just which customers have booked a tour. So given the data, I think only Peter and Mary would be there. Paul only booked 2 of the 3 tours.

Comment: Sorry i've just updated my question @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your data is and what your question is, this will involve finding out who has not scheduled all of the tours and then finding all customers who aren't in the previous list.

I'm not sure I like it, but something like this gets just Peter and Mary, since they are the only two who have scheduled all 3 tours:

```
SELECT c1.custid, c1.custName 
FROM #customers c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT c2.custid
    FROM #tours t
    CROSS JOIN #customers c2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #tour_detail td ON td.tourid = t.tourid 
        AND td.custid = c2.custid
    WHERE td.custid IS NULL
) noCustTour ON c1.custid = noCustTour.custid
WHERE noCustTour.custid IS NULL
```

Comment: To explain, the inner query joins all tours to all customers to get a list of all possible combinations of customers and tours, then joins to the schedule to see who doesn't have a scheduled tour. Then the outer query excludes any customer who shows up in the list of not having a tour scheduled.

Comment: I prefer the LEFT JOIN..WHERE NULL (or NOT NULL depending on situation) syntax to the NOT IN syntax. It lets the optimizer work more efficiently, and for large datasets, it's _A LOT_ faster.

Comment: Thanks for your clear expaination, it works perfectly ! @Shawn